# Кавычки и прописная буква в названии праздника

Tags: прописная-строчная, названия, кавычки

В Доме досуга прошел праздник Семик, или, как его еще называют, праздник Русской березки. Нужно ли названия праздников заключать в кавычки, правильно ли слово русской с прописной буквы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Доме досуга прошел праздник Семик, или, как его еще называют, праздник Русской березки.

Пояснение

Троицкие праздники - это целый комплекс праздничных мероприятий с различными названиями: День Святой Троицы, Зеленые святки, Троицкие святки, Русальная неделя и др.

Также в эти дни отмечаются фольклорные праздники, посвященные культу березы, которые носят условные названия. Обычно слово "праздник" в название не включается (это приложение, родовое наименование), название праздника пишется с прописной буквы, также возможно использование кавычек.

Вот примеры: праздник Русской березки, праздник "Русская березка". Есть вариант:  «Праздник русской березки — Троица», тогда слово  "праздник" включено в название, но при этом используются кавычки.

Справочная информация

Семик — восточнославянский праздник весенне-летнего календарного периода; отмечается на седьмой четверг после Пасхи, за три дня до Троицы.

Троица является одним из православных, который отмечается на 50 день после Пасхи, в воскресенье.В народной традиции Троицей называется и отмечается как праздник либо один день (воскресенье), либо три дня (с воскресенья по вторник).

Берёза —  центральный объект в Семик и Троицу, ей посвящено множество обрядов. Береза одна из первых одевалась в яркую нарядную зелень. Не случайно существовало поверье, что именно береза обладает особой силой роста и что нужно эту силу использовать. Березовыми ветками украшали окна, дома, дворы, ворота, на церковной службе стояли с березовыми ветками, веря, что они обладают целебной силой.

Comment: А как быть с кавычками в следующих примерах: МБУК ЦМБС- надо ли выделять кавычками ЦМБС.  МБУК "Центральная межпоселенческая библиотечная система"- здесь понятно, а вот при аббревиатуре кавычки сохраняются? Я только нашла типа: ОАО "РЖД", ОАО "МТС", но это названия коммерческих организаций. А как в моем примере? Надеюсь на Ваш ответ. Спасибо.

Comment: Полагаю, что принцип в этих названиях один и тот же:  кавычки используются не только для обозначения условного названия, но и ОБОЗНАЧАЮТ ГРАНИЦЫ между двумя тематическими наименованиями предприятия. Тогда можно записать: МБУК "ЦМБС".

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ.

Comment: Vera, подскажите, как правильно: Нарушение выявлено в кабинете информатики МБОУ Алтунинская оош или МБОУ Алтунинской оош. Названия без кавычек. Кстати, оош -с прописной или строчной?